# How to copy the dynamic table data from web page and paste it into existing Excel using selenium with Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid, selenium-rc

I copied and pasted into Excel sheet but it is coming like 1 column is filled with 1 cell , 2nd column is filled with 2nd cell and 3rd column is filled with 3rd cell.
But I want row wise without skip cell value
Example:

My output:
| Column A | Column B |Column C
| -------- | -------- |--------
|  123     |          |                                            |          |  234     |
|          |          |  345
|  134     |          |
|          |  245     |
|          |          |  356

Actual output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 234 | 345 |
| 134 | 245 | 356 |

Thank you in advance for spending your valuable time to helping me.